# Receive Error in import opencv in python

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have installed OpenCV successfully using brew on my mac with OS X 10.10.3. Created the symbolic link as well to the cv.py and cv.so files. 
when I use the import command in python I receive the following error:

> $ python
>   Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>    import cv2
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: dlopen(./cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libImath-2_2.12.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
>     Reason: image not found